# Delete Admin on model button clicked ok with ajax request in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete the admin with ajax. When the ok button is click an ajax request is generated and the admin is deleted against this request but the problem is that I can't able to get the ajax response. 
if the ajax call is made, Process_Delete_Admin file i am calling can not returns anything. but the network tab in the inspector provide me this details

Request URL:http://localhost/StudentGuideBook/process/Process_Delete_Admin.php?action=removeAdmin
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:80

Any help please.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
        bootbox.confirm({
            size: "small",
            message: "Are you sure to delete?",
            callback: function(result){
                if (result === true){
                    var AdminID= $(this).attr('id');
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:'http://localhost/StudentGuideBook/process/Process_Delete_Admin.php?action=removeAdmin',
                        data:{AdminID:AdminID},
                        type:"POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status == "Success") {
                                alert("Done");
                            } else {
                                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })

    });
```

```html
Ajax request point this file (Process_Delete_Admin) containing this code

<?php

 session_start();
 require_once '../models/admin.php';

 if (isset($_SESSION['obj_admin'])) {
 $obj_admin = unserialize($_SESSION['obj_admin']);
 } else {
 $obj_admin = new Admin();
 }


echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

die;
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$key = ($_GET['AdminID']);
$obj_admin->delete_admin($key);

}
$_SESSION['obj_admin'] = serialize($obj_admin);

header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

 ?>
```

Comment: What is the response you receive back, in your network inspector?

Comment: <pre>Array
(
)
</pre>

Comment: I don't see you sending `success` back anywhere. `echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'))`. Try adding that after your delete call. I'm not sure why you'd want to set the header location while making an ajax call.

Comment: Check your Headers panel, and see what it says as the parameters. There may be some confusion since you're sending both GET (`?action=removeAdmin`) and POST (`{AdminID:AdminID}`).

Comment: yes sir now am getting the both parameters but can not get the successfull now this is happening 
Request URL:http://localhost/StudentGuideBook/process/Process_Delete_Admin.php?action=removeAdmin
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:80

and params contains action='removeAdmin' and AdminID:'9'

Comment: For some reason, it's not seeing your $_POST. Try printing $_REQUEST instead and see if you get anything that way.